# Bootstrap : Is it possible to add search form on carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3. I've just created the home page with carousel slider. It's work well. I have to add a search form on the page. I'd like to know if it is possible to add the search form on carousel. So even if the carousel image change, the form always remains on the current slide ( Like on the web Air b and b https://fr.airbnb.com/)
Is it possible with Bootstrap 3 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example: http://bootply.com/108847

The `#searchForm` will overlay the carousel using:

```
#searchForm {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the site you linked, they are using an absolutely positioned div to keep the search form in place while the carousel changes. That's probably your best bet for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap4 Background Image carousel with search form:

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/aq9Laaew/218909/)

```
Code needs to move search form to carousel slider
   #searchForm {
      position:absolute;
      top:45%;
      left: 32%;
    }
```